# asp.net MVC 3/4 equivalent to a response.filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, response.filter

I am in a need to intercept all of the html that will be sent to the browser and replace some tags that are there. this will need to be done globally and for every view. what is the best way to do this in ASP.NET MVC 3 or 4 using C#? In past I have done this in ASP.net Webforms using the 'response.filter' in the Global.asax (vb)

```
Private Sub Global_PreRequestHandlerExecute(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.PreRequestHandlerExecute
    Response.Filter = New ReplaceTags(Response.Filter)
End Sub
```

this calls a class I created that inherits from the system.io.stream and that walked through the html to replace all the tags. 
I have no idea as to how to do this in ASP.NET MVC 4 using C#. As you might have noticed I am a completely newbee in the MVC world.

Comment: Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: This answer shows you how to use a response filter to rewrite the resulting HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8382617/64750

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could still use a response filter in ASP.NET MVC:

```
public class ReplaceTagsFilter : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly Stream _response;
    public ReplaceTagsFilter(Stream response)
    {
        _response = response;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        var html = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        html = ReplaceTags(html);
        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
        _response.Write(buffer, offset, buffer.Length);
    }

    private string ReplaceTags(string html)
    {
        // TODO: go ahead and implement the filtering logic
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then write a custom action filter which will register the response filter:

```
public class ReplaceTagsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Filter = new ReplaceTagsFilter(response.Filter);
    }
}
```

and now all that's left is decorate the controllers/actions that you want to be applied this filter:

```
[ReplaceTags]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

or register it as a global action filter in Global.asax if you want to apply to all actions.

Comment: Filter only appears to execute when the code exits the OnActionExecuting function. How can I access the stream buffer before the response is actually written out?

Comment: The whole point of a Response filter is to modify the Response stream. But in order to be able to modify it, this stream must first be written.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with Razor. I am getting "Filtering is not allowed" HttpException when trying to add a filter to the response.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov According to one of the guys from the ASP.NET team: [**Response filters are not supported with Razor because of the way Razor buffers output**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1634304.aspx#4216340).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is correct but. After using it for a while I came across a case when the response is split in many parts so that html is incorrect

```
Part 1: 
<html>.....<labe

Part 2: 
l/>...</html>
```

Also partial renders may make unexpected cases. Their html is out of the main stream too.
So my solution is to do it in the Flush method after all streaming is done.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Insert messages and script to display on client when a partial view is returned
    /// </summary>
    private class ResponseFilter : MemoryStream
    {
        private readonly Stream _response;
        private readonly IList<object> _detachMessages;

        public override void Flush()
        {

            // add messages and remove
            // filter is called for a number of methods on one page (BeginForm, RenderPartial...)
            // so that we don't need to add it more than once

            var html = MessageAndScript(_detachMessages);
            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);
            _detachMessages.Clear();
            _response.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            base.Flush();
        }

        public ResponseFilter(Stream response, IList<object> detachMessages)
        {
            _response = response;
            _detachMessages = detachMessages;
        }

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            _response.Write(buffer, offset, buffer.Length);    
        }

        private static string MessageAndScript(IList<object> detachMessages)
        {

            if (detachMessages.Count == 0)
                return null;

            var javascript = CustomJavaScriptSerializer.Instance.Serialize(detachMessages);

            return "$(function(){var messages = " + javascript + @";
// display messages
base.ajaxHelper.displayMessages(messages);
})";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've experienced that when the stream splits I end up with a lot of weird "??" symbols in the source code, thus making the page look weird. Did you encounter this?