# Custom HTML adjustment filter in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I need my ASP.NET MVC application to inject some html into a razor view `div` element that is marked with a specific css class.

For example, if in Razor I have:

```
<div class="editable">
</div>
```

I want to have a C# logic that inspects the rendered Razor views and injects some other elements.

The resulting html would contain a button:

```
<div class="editable">
    <div class="edit-button"></div>   
</div>
```

Is there a meachanism in ASP.NET MVC that allows me to achieve such injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify the output of a response, add a [response filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.filter.aspx). See [asp.net MVC 3/4 equivalent to a response.filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591651/asp-net-mvc-3-4-equivalent-to-a-response-filter) for an example to seletively apply a response filter using MVC attributes.

Using such a filter you can access the content of a page before it sent to the client. To modify the HTML you could use the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

I wonder if it isn't possible for you to generate the proper markup in the views in the first place.

If you feel that you're doing redundant things, consider using

- [partial views](http://rachelappel.com/razor/partial-views-in-asp-net-mvc-3-w-the-razor-view-engine/),
- [custom HTML helper extensions](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs), or
- [Razor helpers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx)

Comment: Please note that according to one of the guys from the ASP.NET team, [**Response filters are not supported with Razor because of the way Razor buffers output**](http://forums.asp.net/t/1634304.aspx#4216340). You will get an error "Filtering is not allowed".