# Save original response data and replace them using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to get response data (incuding html markup) on server and then replace them to anothe one and send to the client.
Is where the best way to do this?

Response.OutputStream is closed for reading.
So what can I use for reading data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to get response data (incuding html markup) in controller

For obvious reasons that's not possible. The response HTML is generated when the view executes, at a much later stage after the controller action has finished executing.

If you want to modify the response HTML you could write a [`response filter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10596288/29407).

Comment: Yes you are right. But may be we can use ActionFilterAttribute OnResultExecuted method? As I understand responce filter execute when response send to the client? Isn't it?

Comment: No, response filter is executed before the response is sent to the client.